# Make clickable button Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I try to develop an apps form Smartphone to a Moverio SmartGlass.

I found a problem that I can't solve. When I use the smartphone I always can use the touch screen to click to a button. But with my SmartGlass I have just a pad. So when my menu appears my button stay un-clickable.

My question is, how to pre-select the button (there is just one button) to make it clickable with ok button on the pad.

NB: I tried to use directional arrows on the pad to select the button but that doesn't work.
[Button to make pre-selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1CPS.jpg)

A part of my unity script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class StepWindow : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rect windowSize = new Rect(15,15,420,300);
    private Rect buttonSize = new Rect (10, 235, 400, 50);
    private Rect labelSize1 = new Rect (10, 25, 400, 50);
    private Rect labelSize2 = new Rect (10, 65, 400, 50);
    private Rect labelSize3 = new Rect (10, 105, 400, 50);
    private Rect labelSize4 = new Rect (10, 145, 400, 50);

    private string strEtape1 = "1. Scannez l'armoire ";
    private string strEtape2 = "2. Ouvrez l'armoire ";
    private string strEtape3 = "3. Localisez les switchs";
    private string strEtape4 = "4. Réarmez le disjoncteur";

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        //Debug.Log ("Utils.isScenarioStarted() : "+ Utils.isScenarioStarted() + " - state : " + StateMachine.instance.state);
        if (Utils.isScenarioStarted())
            GUI.Window (0, windowSize,MyWindow, "Etapes");
    }

    private void MyWindow(int id)
    {
        GUIStyle defaultTextStyle = new GUIStyle ();
        defaultTextStyle.normal.textColor = Color.white;
        defaultTextStyle.fontSize = 20;
        GUIStyle redCurrent = new GUIStyle();
        redCurrent.normal.textColor = Color.red;
        redCurrent.fontSize = 25;

        switch(StateMachine.instance.state)
        {
        case StateMachine.State.INIT:
            if (GUI.Button(buttonSize, "Commencer"))
            {
                StateMachine.instance.state = StateMachine.State.SCAN_RACK;
            }
            break;
        case StateMachine.State.SCAN_RACK:  
            GUI.Label (labelSize1, strEtape1 + Utils.getAlarmName(), redCurrent); 
            if (GUI.Button(buttonSize, "Suivant")) //this button
            {
                // test Franck 
                StateMachine.instance.state = StateMachine.State.OPEN_RACK;
            }
            break;

.....
.....
```

Have you any solution ..?

Thanks !

Comment: Couple of things, you are not using Unityscript, this is C# (no biggy tho). Mostly, you should forget about the legacy UI (OnGUI method) and move to the new system. Adding a button is fairly easy then, and entirely visual.

Comment: Hi @Franck_Cordu you ***can not*** use the ancient "gui" system (you must have seen some old posts about it).  Fortunately it's ***incredibly easy*** to use the ordinary system built-in to unity.  (1) click "add canvas" (2) click "add Button"  (3) .. there is no "3", you're finished. Go home and relax

Comment: you can find a million posts on here about it example http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124638/294884

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers but I can't change shift to the "new" gui system because, It's not my code and I have to improve this code to make it usable on others devices.

So, there is a solution to my probleme using the ancient gui or not ..?